# ListBox OnClick event not firing after SpinEdit OnExit event changes ListBox.Font.Size

Tags: delphi, events, onclick, listbox, delphi-5

I have a ListBox on my form with an OnClick event registered to it. This event works as intended, except for one particular situation:

My form contains a SpinEdit (values 8-12), to let the user adjust the ListBox.Font.Size property (I also adjust the ListBox.ItemHeight property is accordingly). These adjustments are done in the SpinEdits OnExit event and also work as intended.

The problem however occurs when the SpinEdit is selected, the value is changed and then the ListBox is clicked. So what **should** happen is:

1. SpinEdit OnExit fired: ListBox.Font.Size adjusted.
2. ListBox OnClick fired: subsequent actions defined in the OnClick event.

But in reality, only the SpinEdits OnExit is fired and the fontsize is adjusted correctly, but the OnClick event of ListBox does not fire. Not that big a deal in itself, but after that point the entire ListBox has become unresponsive to mouseclicks!

Noteworthy observations:

1. Switching back and forth to another application/window and back to
   my application: responsiveness of the ListBox is regained.
2. After triggering the problem, interacting with a CheckListBox that is on the same form, followed by clicking on the ListBox fires the ListBox Onclick event.
3. Triggering the SpinEdits OnExit event with the Enter key introduces no problems.
4. The form contains a few more SpinEdit objects with OnExit events, that do not change properties of the ListBox. Exiting these SpinEdits by clicking the ListBox works just fine, with the OnClick event executed right after the SpinEdits OnExit event.

Comment: Do not describe your code, post a [mcve].

Comment: Sounds like your code might be changing focus during a focus change, I had similar behavior caused by that. Maybe try SpinEdit's `OnChange` event instead of `OnExit`, something that doesn't relate to focus changes? Hard to say what happens without code to reproduce, as Sertac mentioned.

Comment: @nil your comment got me thinking in another direction and led me to replacing the spinedit with a combobox, which works fine and introduces no problems, so thanks for that! Concerning the post itself: since I still find this weird behaviour and I'm still learning about Delphi, I will try to replicate the problem in a minimal code example and update the post in the coming days, if I find time for that. Thanks for both your comments and time.